# How to set environment variable while posting data to API in Postman

Tags: api, postman

I have few `APIs` which uses a variable `instance` with values as `dev`, `test` and `prod`. These values are used in the variable so that the API remains the same and the data can be posted to different environments like `dev`, `test`, `prod`. These `APIs` are deployed on `azure platform`

I am using postman to publish data to the API. I have created an environment variable and set its value as dev. I want to know where in the api url I should include this variable in order to successfully send the data.

API Url:

`https://ashtechdev.azurewebsites.net/tempdata`

Comment: I think that's a bad idea. What will stop your users from changing the environment on their own? You should have a separate deployment for each environment, and in POSTMAN you would call different URLs using Variables.

Comment: @HubertJarema You mean separate API URL for each environment.?

Comment: Yes. Then you can lock out other environments from public access. You also specify different configurations per each environment based on your deployment location etc. If you pass in your configuration in the URL, anyone who will figure out you're doing it, will be able to switch the environment. Also, when you make a deployment to development, you'll be making a deployment to production at the same time - not ideal. How would you catch errors before production?

Answer (score 0):

I have posted my answer here in this below [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53410958/10121996). Please use the same.

Hope this helps.