# How to pass multiple variables as Header Request in the postman?

Tags: postman

How to pass ***multiple variables as Header Request*** in the postman?

Comment: question seems very vague, maybe you could add all the variables to an object and send the object as a request header

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this as follows-

1. Create environment variables in your postman.  If you dont know how
   to create environment variables the use this [link](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/02/20/using-variables-inside-postman-and-collection-runner/).
2. Use the variables in your Header like this-

[image]

Benefit of the environment variables is you can use multiple variables and its values and it optimze your work efforts.

Hope this helps.